# Fundamental Unit in cylotomic fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

What is the fundamental unit of $Q(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is the primitive $n$-th root of the
unity?

Is there an explicit algorithm to compute it?

I could find https://mathoverflow.net/a/204551/111528 on mathoverflow.

Comment: These cyclotomic fields don't just have **one** fundamental unit each.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Could you please give some reference for that?

Comment: It's Dirichlet's unit theorem.

Comment: There are enough so called cyclotomic units $u_k=(1-\zeta_n^k)/(1-\zeta_n)$, $\gcd(k,n)=1$. Together with $\zeta_n$ they generate a finite index subgroup of $\mathcal{O}^*$. IIRC the exact index is not known in general. Observe that $\zeta_n$ is a power of $\zeta_n^k$, so both $u_k$ and its reciprocal are in $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a bit more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit). Apparently I was wrong about the finite index stuff (unless $n$ is a power of a prime). I need to recalibrate a bit...